# Masked ImageView has black background on Android 5

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview

I'm overriding ImageView's onDraw method to apply a radius to the image and it used to work fine, however it has a minor issue on Android 5. In fact it works on a Galaxy S II (4.1) and Nexus 4 (4.4.4), but not on the Nexus 5 (5.0.1).

On the Nexus 5 there is a black background drawn behind the rounded image that I'm not getting rid off! When I turn the phone orientation for instance, the black background is gone.

```
class Avatar extends ImageView
{
    private RectF rectangle = new RectF()

    private Paint paint1 = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG )

    private Paint paint2 = new Paint()

    public Avatar()
    {
         paint2.setXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode( Mode.SRC_IN ) )
    }

    override void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
    {
        final Drawable drawable = getDrawable

        if( drawable == null )
        {
            super.onDraw( canvas )
            return
        }

        rectangle.set( 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() )
        int restore = canvas.saveLayer( rectangle, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG )
        canvas.drawRoundRect( rectangle, 50, 50, paint1 )
        canvas.saveLayer( rectangle, paint2, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG )
        super.onDraw( canvas )
        canvas.restoreToCount( restore )
    }
}
```

*Please ignore syntactic errors or the invalid constructor as I loosely translated this from Scala*

Comment: I'm quite sure you're not supposed to call super twice on the same method, ever. Have you tried locking and unlocking the canvas before drawing?

Comment: After revising the code, you're not cleaning out the canvas to transparent and I can't remember it on top of my mind but you may be clipping the redraw area too.

Comment: are you just trying to create a round imageview?

Comment: Super will never be called twice if you look closely. The return keyword in the if statement finishes the method right there. What do you mean by clean out to transparent? I tried to first call canvas.drawColor with transparent, but that did not change anything at all!

Comment: @tyczj I'm trying to create an ImageView that works with an arbitrary radius parameter!

Comment: Then why not use `RoundedBitmapDrawable` which does exactly what you want http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html

Comment: Well, I was not completely honest. I'm actually trying to create a Scala Trait that I can mix into eveyr View as I please. This solution used to work well, until now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was created by hardware acceleration. I was showing a placeholder avatar, which is rendered from SVG and required me to disable hardware acceleration. Then, when the actual bitmap finished loading, I replaced the SVG with the bitmap but didn't switch hardware acceleration back on.

I was now able to get rid of the ugly black background. However I still don't understand why the code fails on the Nexus 5 when hardware acceleration is disabled, while it works perfectly fine on the other devices!